# For Loop with return won't exit

Tags: javascript, for-loop, return-value

I have two arrays:

**Matches**

```
var matches = [
{ playerId: 1, matchId: 1 },

{ playerId: 2, matchId: 1  },

{ playerId: 3, matchId: 2 }];
```

**Players**

```
var players= [
{ name: "Ronaldo", id: 1 },
{ name: "Messi", id: 2 },
{ name: "Zlatan" id: 3 }];
```

I want to list all players who played on match with `matchId 1`;

```
for (i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {

    if (matches[i].matchId == 1)
    {
        var p = matches[i].playerId;
        //alert(p);
        var currentName = getPlayersInfo(p);
        alert(currentName);

    }
}

function getPlayersInfo(id){
  var curID = id;
  var name;
  for (i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {

    if (players[i].id == curID) {
       name = players[i].name;
    }
  }

       return name;
}
```

If I have just `alert(p);` instead of that I call `getPlayersInfo(p)` than I am getting `alert` two times with id `1` and `2` and that works fine but with `getPlayersInfo(p)` first `alert` is `Ronaldo` and than I am getting `alert` `Messi` multiply times.

What I am doing wrong in `getPlayersInfo()` ?

Comment: What is `players`? Where is that defined?

Comment: @Phil I edited now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting the same `i` variable (which is global) because you aren't declaring it with `var`. In your `for` loops, use

```
for (var i = 0; ...
```

---

Another solution would be

```
for (var i = 0, l = matches.length; i < l; i++) {
    var match = matches[i];
    if (match.matchId === 1) {
        var name = players.find(function(player) {
            return player.id === match.playerId;
        });
        alert(name); // note, could be "undefined"
    }
}
```

---

If you have to look players up by their ID regularly, consider creating a map (ES2015 syntax for brevity)

```
let playersById = players.reduce((map, player) => {
    map[player.id] = player;
    return map;
}, Object.create(null));
```

then you can simply reference

```
playersById[match.playerId];
```